# Android - Zooming on only Position (0,0) instead whole image

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, imageview

I am currently working on a project and where I have added an `Image` class to a `Linear layout` as a view, now I am trying to zoom in on the Image class using the scale example from: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale

I have used that example to the dot and have made no changes.

However, the scaling only works at `Position (0,0)` and I can not scale to other parts of the Image. Regardless where I gesture from it only zooms towards `Position (0,0)`

If anyone would suggest me some changes to make this work. That would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to scale up/down to a different point, you must specify the pivot point coordinates.

Based on the example from training docs, you are using the `canvas.scale(x,y)` method.  But as you can see from the [Canvas class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#scale(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)), there is an overload of that method that takes the pivot coordinates as well.
So to scale to the middle for example you might use:

```
canvas.scale(x,y,width/2,height/2)
```

Comment: This works but it zooms in the middle. Is there a way to zoom at the position the gesture is started from?

Comment: Like I said, it will zoom into whatever the pivot you set. Simply save the coordinates from the gesture and use them here